# EF core 5 - Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Not sure why, but I get an error

> Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

when running this query. What am I doing wrong?

```
var case = caseRepo
            .Many(c => c.Id == caseId)
            .Include(c => c.Progresses as AesProgress)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.ProgressType)
            .Include(c => c.Progresses as AesProgress)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Situation)
            .Include(c => c.AesCaseCategories)
                .ThenInclude(acc => acc.ExpertSupportNomination)
            .Include(c => c.LegalBasisList)
                .ThenInclude(l => l.AssessedAccordingToLaw)
            .Include(c => c.AesCaseCategories)
                .ThenInclude(acc => acc.PendingLawsuit)
            .Include(c => c.AesCaseCategories)
                .ThenInclude(acc => acc.Injury)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Maybe test first which one triggers this issue?

Comment: Sorry, the .SingleOrDefault() is causing the issue

Comment: What are your 'as' expressions trying to achieve? I suspect they may be the problem.

Comment: Please include the full exception message - EFC 5 should be including the text of the expression causing it. `c => c.Progresses as AesProgress` for sure is invalid.

Comment: I'm guessing that `Progresses` & `AesProgress` represent a type hierarchy? And that `ProgressType` and `Situation` are navigation properties, on one sub-type in that hierarchy? I think you need to move the cast down a level. `.Include(c => c.Progresses).ThenInclude(p => (p as AesProgress).ProgressType)`